# Sql Query Not Updating The Path Of Img File

Tags: php, mysql

There isn't a singlle tutorial on how to upload image file through file syste and save its path in sql database.
And its mentioned on some sites but no explained properly.
Nyway
I am uploading an image through php and i want to store the path of the uploaded image in the sql database.
I have 2 pages

1.) insert.php

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["MM_Username"]))
{
    $_SESSION["message"] = "Please Login";
}

?>
 <!--next comes the form, you must set the enctype to "multipart/frm-data" 
and use an input type "file" -->
 <form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  
action="chkupload.php">
 <table>
    <tr><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload image">
       </td></tr>
 </table>   
 </form>
```

this page works absolutely fine but the problem is in the next file

2)chkupload.php

The problem is that the upload works fine & It creates the file in the images/ folder but does not save the path of it in the sql table. So basically i need help with this.
Also its under user authentication. Its a profile picture.

```
  <?php require_once('Connections/mb.php'); 

$loginUsername = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];

//define a maxim size for the uploaded images in Kb
 define ("MAX_SIZE","100"); 

//This function reads the extension of the file. It is used to determine if the
// file  is an image by checking the extension.
 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

//This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no 
// error  found)  
//and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures.  
//If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
 $errors=0;
//checks if the form has been submitted
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
 {
    //reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    //if it is not empty
    if ($image) 
    {
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and 
        // will not  upload the file,  
    //otherwise we will do more tests
 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension !=
 "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {
        //print error message
            echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {
//get the size of the image in bytes
 //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
 //in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
 $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
}

//we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
$image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
//the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images 
//folder)
$newname="images/".$image_name;
//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if (!$copied) 
{
    echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
}}}}

//If no errors registred, print the success message
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
 {
    echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!</h1>";
 }



mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
mysql_select_db("musibridge") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to Database";
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE artist92 SET path= $newname WHERE email = $loginUsername") 
or die(mysql_error());  

 ?>
```

The error generated is

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\MB\chkupload.php on line 3
File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!
Connected to MySQL
Connected to DatabaseYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'jpg WHERE email =' at line 1

Please help me fix this. Its uploading but not updating the column path of the table artist92

This is my login page.Adding it just for your reference for session variable 
artlog.php

```
 <?php require_once('Connections/mb.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_Recordsetartist = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_Recordsetartist = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_mb, $mb);
$query_Recordsetartist = sprintf("SELECT * FROM artist92 WHERE email = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordsetartist, "text"));
$Recordsetartist = mysql_query($query_Recordsetartist, $mb) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordsetartist = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetartist);
$totalRows_Recordsetartist = mysql_num_rows($Recordsetartist);
$query_Recordsetartist = "SELECT * FROM artist92";
$Recordsetartist = mysql_query($query_Recordsetartist, $mb) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordsetartist = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetartist);
$totalRows_Recordsetartist = mysql_num_rows($Recordsetartist);

$colname_Recordsetartist = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_email'])) {
  $colname_Recordsetartist = $_SESSION['MM_email'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_mb, $mb);
$query_Recordsetartist = sprintf("SELECT * FROM artist92 WHERE email = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordsetartist, "text"));
$Recordsetartist = mysql_query($query_Recordsetartist, $mb) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordsetartist = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetartist);

$colname_Recordsetartist = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_email'])) {
  $colname_Recordsetartist = $_SESSION['MM_email'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_mb, $mb);
$query_Recordsetartist = sprintf("SELECT * FROM artist92 WHERE email = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordsetartist, "text"));
$Recordsetartist = mysql_query($query_Recordsetartist, $mb) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordsetartist = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetartist);
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['email'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "artistprofile.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "artlog.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_mb, $mb);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT email, password FROM artist92 WHERE email=%s AND password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $mb) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to call `session_start()` before trying to access the session. And I'm just wondering, is "artist92" the name of a table?

Answer (score 0):

First, like Omer already said:

You must call `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION` variables.

Then take a minute and think about what your SQL query would actually generate:

```
$newname = "C:\\My Documents\\image.jpg";
$loginUsername = "someone";
echo "UPDATE artist92 SET path= $newname WHERE email = $loginUsername";
```

The output would be:

```
UPDATE artist92 SET path= C:\\My Documents\\image.jpg WHERE email = someone
```

How should MySQL interpret that statement? - It can't.
You would at least have to add quotes around strings.

```
UPDATE artist92 SET path= "C:\\My Documents\\image.jpg" WHERE email = "someone"
```

However that is still a **major security issue**. 
Read the PHP article on [SQL Injection](http://www.php.net/manual/security.database.sql-injection.php) for an explanation. No, really - read it!

Also you don't validate that the file was actually uploaded. You should check out `is_uploaded_file()` and `move_uploaded_file()` functions.

Comment: THanks for helping but i am still getting error
Notice: Undefined index: MM_Username in C:\xampp\htdocs\MB\chkupload.php on line 5
but the sql error is gone.
I also checked my table artist92 and in it i found the path wasnt updated though its not showing any error in the sql syntax anymore..

Answer (score 0):

You need single-quotes around $newname in your UPDATE statement. That will fix the error in your SQL syntax. 
Also, "Undefined variable: _SESSION" can be resolved by calling session_start()

Comment: yup the session_start() worked..thanks..
and also thr is no syntax error anymore..
i did this
'$result = mysql_query("UPDATE artist92 SET path= '$newname' WHERE email = '$loginUsername'") 
or die(mysql_error());  '
but its not updating the path in the table artist92.
its also displaying the error 
Undefined index: MM_Username in C:\xampp\htdocs\MB\chkupload.php on line 5
MM_username is a session variable.

Comment: $_SESSION is a superglobal and always present, even if a session hasn't been started. It'll just be an empty array.